# Expo app doesn't load react native app due to "unexpected url" error

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm developing ReactNative app with [Expo](http://expo.io).

From time to time something goes wrong and during app loading following error happens

[image]

Now I noticed that this error is reproduced when I enable hot reloading on android device or emulator. But hot reloading used to work sometimes ago.
It looks like that port number (-1) in the URL leads to it.

The project is initialized with `exp i` and started with `exp start` commands.

`exp` version: 37.0.1
OS: Linux
Mobile device/emulator: Android 6.0

Comment: I've found a related bug report on expo forums https://forums.expo.io/t/error-when-enabling-hot-reloading/265